# How a non constructor method inside a custom Exception class is accessed in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I came across the following code while searching for custom Exceptions in Java.

```
class MyException extends Exception{
    String str1;
    MyException(String str2) {
       str1=str2;
    }
    public String toString(){ 
       return ("Output String = "+str1) ;
    }
}

public class CustomException{
    public static void main(String args[]){
       try{
          throw new MyException("Custom");
       } catch(MyException exp) {
          System.out.println("This is catch block") ;
          System.out.println(exp) ;
       }
    }
}
```

Its output is: 
This is catch block 
Output String = Custom

But I can't get my head around how the toString() method of MyException class gets called.
Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing items to console, the `.toString()` method of the object provided gets called automatically within the `println` method or any of its dependencies, as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-):

> public void println(Object x)
>
> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at
>   first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then
>   behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().
>
> Parameters:
>
> x - The Object to be printed.

EDIT: As per your comment, the `print` and `println` methods might behave differently for different parameters, as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), however, for non primitive types, the behavior is the same (that is, when printing to console the object's `.toString()` method is invoked).

Comment: Thanx. But Does this apply to instances of all generic classes?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `System.out.println(exp);` it invokes [`String.valueOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) which calls `toString()`. That is, it is equivalent to `System.out.println(exp.toString());`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(exp) ;` passes your exception instance to a `println` method of an instance of `PrintStream`. `println` calls `String.valueOf(x);` for the passed instance `x`, which calls the instance's `toString` method (if the passed reference is not null). Thus your `toString` method is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Its happening when you call `System.out.println(exp) ;`

When you call [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) class method  [print(exp)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.Object)) method then internally it calls `write` method with argument as `String.valueOf(exp)`.

If you see source of [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) method in [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class thats where toString gets called.

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

From [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.Object))

> **print(Object obj)**-Prints an object. The string produced by the String.valueOf(Object)
>   method is translated into bytes according to the platform's default
>   character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner
>   of the write(int) method.